# Block direct access to .php but allow AngularJS $http requests

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess

Is there any way of blocking direct access to .php files in my **ctrl** foler, but allowing http requests from an Angular app? I have a .htaccess with 'Deny from all' in the ctrl folder at the moment which blocks access but it also blocks the Angular calls.

I imagine there isn't a way, but I'm not a whizz at PHP so I wanted to ask.

AngularJS

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/ctrl/login/login.php',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    data: credentials
})
```

Comment: Have you tried to search the web for "API Auth"? There are a lot of approaches that deal with secure a web API. E.g. token auth or simple use same origin policy.

Comment: I'm looking for something more general rather than login specific.

Comment: same origin policy.

Comment: I wonder what you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: do you want to allow only internal requests from your host?

Comment: What I wanted to do is only allow access to login.php or signup.php if the requests are coming from the index page. I did it with .htaccess in the end and specified a referral URL.

Comment: And why would you want that? If it has to do with some kind of security, please be aware that the referrer can be spoofed.

Comment: How so? And what you would you recommend as an alternative? I've read about placing these files outside of your public_html (I'm using GoDaddy) but I'm not sure what path to use to get to them. I basically don't want to anyone to directly go to one of my scripts and enter rogue data, e.g. like on a sign up form to create an account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is. In fact, an http request to these .php files from an angular app is nothing more than 'a direct access to .php files'. If the angular app (which lives client-side) could do the request, the client itself could do the request as well.

Comment: That's what I thought. What I wanted to do is only allow access to login.php or signup.php if the requests are coming from the index page. I did it with .htaccess in the end by specified a referral URL which the Angular app is working on.